# Auth0 token and refresh token gets deleted on Ionic app close

Tags: auth0

I used [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/hybrid/ionic/php) to implement auth0 on Ionic. Everything works fine but when I close the app and open it again I see that token and refresh token get deleted from localstorage but not the profile token. If I don't have internet access I can't browse my app. I need to browse my app offline since I store other data in localstorage which is used while browsing offline. What am I missing?

Comment: Without seeing your code I can only make guesses. Have you checked that you aren't signing the user out anywhere? Or that the expiry of your tokens isn't  too short?

Comment: @KassandraPerch please chabi the link I posted. I followed that tutorial line by line. I'm not logging out anywhere, when the app is closed and re opened the tokens are not there so when I click log in button it says you have previously logged in with xyz account when that is clicked the app logs in without asking password but this needs internet connectivity